# How to avoid or minimize a split brain with 3 nodes in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to read the different recommendations here and there, but I still don't see how with 3 nodes we solve the problem over two nodes.

If I have A<->B<->C<->A node and A <-> B network connection is down, how to avoid the possibility to form 2 clusters A <-> C and B <-> C running in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A split brain scenario occurs when some of your cluster nodes can't connect to other cluster nodes.

With a large estate - especially geographically distributed - the intermediate link might be lost. If both parts of the cluster are quorate (have enough nodes available as defined in the config) they carry on 'working' and you end up with data going out of sync between the two.

This cannot happen in your scenario, because node C knows that both A and B are online - thus you don't get two separate clusters forming, even if the comms between A and B are offline.

If A was lost entirely, B+C are more than 50% of the nodes - therefore your cluster knows it's 'quorate' and can continue operating normally.

[Enhancements to Zen discovery fixing partial isolation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7493)

Comment: Oh interesting. Do they say this somewhere, is there an official pseudo description of the algorithm ? And what happen in that case ? The system will just be yellow and that's it? I mean still running right ?

Comment: Sorry, too a while to find the link. Knew I had read it somewhere. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7493

Comment: Do I understand correctly? In this case A is the master node with shards and B, C are replicas. So if A goes down, They both will take over as master? If A is not down but communication between B is lost. So B thinks that I should be master because of C still has the communication with, it prevents B to be master. Because if I understand correctly when having 2, A and B, B turns master when cannot communicate with A but at the same time A runs as master as well.